# Is there a way to prevent app users from adding a "prepaid" card as their form of payment?

Tags: stripe-payments, payment-gateway, payment-processing

We have been having issues with users adding a prepaid card as a payment method, which is exactly what we are trying to avoid. We would prefer users to only have the option of adding a credit or debit card.

Cheers.

Comment: I might be wrong but this sounds like an X-Y problem. Why are you having issues with prepaid cards?

Answer (score 2):

you can solve this by examining the card's "funding" property on the tokens returned from Stripe.js (for example) and blocking any cards with `funding=prepaid`:

https://stripe.com/docs/api#token_object-card-funding